# dropdown menu flickers in bootstrap when user moves hovers to the dropdown fast

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

i have a bootstrap menu in my website, in the navbar when the user hovers on any item, a dropdown is shown and again there is a sub dropdown for items in the main dropdown:

[image]

as you can see in the image.

```html
<li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Entertainment </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu animated">
    <li><a href="https://www.booktheparty.in/kids_party-planner/entertainment/MQ/stage_shows">Stage Shows</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.booktheparty.in/kids_party-planner/entertainment/MQ/game_stalls">Game Stalls</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.booktheparty.in/kids_party-planner/entertainment/MQ/entertainment_stalls">Entertainment Stalls</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.booktheparty.in/kids_party-planner/entertainment/MQ/special_effects">Special Effects</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.booktheparty.in/kids_party-planner/entertainment/MQ/mascots">Mascots</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.booktheparty.in/kids_party-planner/entertainment/MQ/photo_&_video">Photo & Video</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.booktheparty.in/kids_party-planner/entertainment/MQ/sound">Sound</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.booktheparty.in/kids_party-planner/entertainment/MQ/rentals">Rentals</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.booktheparty.in/kids_party-planner/entertainment/MQ/tent_wala">Tent Wala</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.booktheparty.in/kids_party-planner/entertainment/MQ/makeup_artists">Makeup Artists</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

this is a sample HTML for an item in main dropdown with sub dropdown. when the user slowly moves the curson to sub dropdown everything is fine, but if a user suddenly moves the cursor to sub dropdown it flickers a lot. i tried making the sub dropdown close to its parent but still the flickering doesn't change.

this is the live link [enter link description here](https://www.booktheparty.in/)
can anyone please tell me what could be wrong here, or how to fix it, it would be great. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Main Navbar which contains the "other events" li , when clicked open the secondary navbar which is overriding the Main Navbar , resulting in flickering as it is not able to identify which navbar you are choosing-:

try choosing another opening transition to the secondary navbar or increasing the padding of Main and secondary navbar.

Hope it works!
cheers

Comment: i didnt understand, can you show as a code or something

Comment: Say you've added an hover animation. That when you hover over an element, it width increases , you shouldn't make the element that you are animating out of the curser position , or you can add a wrapper element and animate it from that.